# How to store user details for further use in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on web application using angularjs. I need the user's email address throughout my application, how can I store it for further use?

Currently what I am doing is:

I have created a user service

```
'use strict';

var module = angular.module('moduleName');

module.factory('UserService',['$resource',function($resource){
    var currentUserEmail = null;
    return {
        getUserResource : function(){
            return $resource('users',{email:'@email'});
        },
        saveCurrentUserEmail : function (email){
            currentUserEmail = email;
        },
        getCurrentUserEmail : function (){
            return currentUserEmail;
        }
    };
}]);
```

At login, I store the user email address using the user service:

```
UserService.saveCurrentUserEmail($scope.username);
```

Now, when I go to another view, in the controller, the user email is what I expect.

```
console.debug("Current User email "+UserService.getCurrentUserEmail());
```

Which prints the user's email address

But when I refresh the page with (ctrl+f5). then the current user email is null.

```
Current User email null
```

What I am doing wrong, or what should I do to save this email address for further use?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting printed user email because before printing it you called your service `UserService.saveCurrentUserEmail($scope.username);`

Now when you refresh your page(ctrl+f5),this service is not called, so it is printed as null because its initialize with null value.

So you need to call `saveCurrentUserEmail` when your page gets load.

Comment: Thanks, but user email is null after that, i can't store it.

Answer (score 0):

On Page refresh you need to make a call to server to check if your is login and update the

```
$scope.username
```

and store it using

```
UserService.saveCurrentUserEmail($scope.username);
```

Or

You can use client side store in browser or use cookie to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore to store user info

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using service, use $cookieStore.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore

`emailAddress` for example is - `"a@a.com"`

```
//That's how i am assigning value
$cookieStore.put('emailAddress', $scope.user.emailAddress);

//thats how i am retrieving it
addr = $cookieStore.get('emailAddress');
```